# The current style does not support customization of this control

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I've a `qml` code which executes fine when build in `QT 6.0.4` but prompt me a runtime error when i build it using `QT 6.5.1`.

The complete error is the following:

```
QML Rectangle: The current style does not support customization of this control (property: "background" item: QQuickRectangle(0x22c49ddefc0, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 100x40)). Please customize a non-native style (such as Basic, Fusion, Material, etc)
```

Below is the portion of code in which the `background` style is present.

```
Button {
    id: listen_btn
    text: "Press Me"
    font.pixelSize: 18
    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 100
        implicitHeight: 40
        border.width: 1
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it with QT 6.5.1 and there is no problem with your code.

Comment: With imports do you use?

Comment: @JürgenLutz:
imports are following: QtQuick,  QtQuick.Window,  QtQuick.Controls and QtQuick.Layouts

Comment: are you using it on macOS or iOS?

Comment: You may need to supply a qtquickcontrols2.conf file as per https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-configuration.html

Comment: @JürgenLutz if this worked for you, I'm guessing you're running on Linux. You can't customize all controls on Windows or Mac.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is about attempting to customize native style.

Have a look here: [QTBUG-109438](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-109438)

This is what the attached change comment says. Take a look at the last paragraph to fix your issue `QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_IGNORE_CUSTOMIZATION_WARNINGS`, but as the comment says "customize native styles on your own risk".

> Warn users when they customize native styles
>
> Since Qt 6, the default style is no longer the Basic style, but
> instead depends on the platform the application is run on. In
> addition, the introduction of the native styles (which are not
> designed to be customized) means that users customizing controls can
> run into visual issues and not understand why.
>
> This patch partially addresses this issue by warning when a native
> control is customized (i.e. a delegate is overridden):
>
> "qrc:/main.qml:11:22: QML QQuickItem: The current style does not
> support customization of this control (property: "contentItem" item:
> QQuickItem(0x1637375d210, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)). Please
> customize a non-native style (such as Basic, Fusion, Material, etc).
> For more information, see:
> [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customization-reference"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customization-reference%22)
>
> ...
>
> [ChangeLog][Important Behavior Changes] Customization of native styles
> will now result in warnings. Non-native styles (such as Basic) should
> be used for customization purposes, or a custom style. If you are
> aware of the risks and still want to customize these controls, you can
> ignore the warnings by setting
> QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_IGNORE_CUSTOMIZATION_WARNINGS to 1.

---

In order to pick a different control style than the default one, there are multiple options depending on your use case. Have a look at the documentation [Using styles in QtQuick Controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-styles.html#using-styles-in-qt-quick-controls).

The simplest would be to use `import QtQuick.Controls.Basic`.