# QML Scrollbar doesn't scroll through all the content

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I created a simple reproducible example of what i want to achieve.
A ListView populated dynamically with strings, content that can be scrolled down as long as there is new content.
But it doesn't work as intended.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.3

Page{

    Connections{
        target: recipeFetcher
    }

    ListView {

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        id: listView

        model: ListModel {
            id: recipeModel
        }

        delegate: Column {

            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 10

            Text {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                width: parent.width - 20
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                text: model.titleText
                color: "white"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }

            Text {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                width: parent.width - 20
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                text: model.ingredientsText
                color: "orange"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }

            Text {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                width: parent.width - 20
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                text: model.instructionsText
                color: "blue"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
        }



        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {

            id: scrollbar

            size: listView.contentHeight / listView.height

            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn

            contentItem: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 5
                color: "orange"
                radius: width
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {

            var strings = [['a'.repeat(3000), 'b'.repeat(3000), 'c'.repeat(3000)], ['a'.repeat(3000), 'b'.repeat(3000), 'c'.repeat(3000)], ['a'.repeat(3000), 'b'.repeat(3000), 'c'.repeat(3000)]]

            for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
               recipeModel.append({titleText: strings[0] + "\n\n", ingredientsText: strings[1] + "\n\n", instructionsText: strings[2] + "\n\n"});
            }

            console.log(listView.contentHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

When You start to scroll down, there won't be more characters that were appended to listView, just nothing, blank page.

contentHeight of the listView is also 0 for some reason after appending strings to the model.

Comment: Hi, please set the answer as accepted if it fixes your problem or add a comment if it needs any modification.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the `ScrollBar`, refer to the [Customizing ScrollBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-customize.html#customizing-scrollbar) documentation.
And when attaching your `ScrollBar` to the `ListView`, there is no need to manually set the `size` property.

> This property is automatically configured when the scroll bar is attached to a flickable. [ScrollBar docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#size-prop)

Also

- Avoid using `anchors.fill: parent` in your `delegate`.
- `Layout.fillHeight` has no effect on `Column`; consider using `ColumnLayout` instead. [ColumnLayout docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html)
- Set `padding` in the parent rather than subtracting it from the item's `width`.
- Import statements can omit version numbers to automatically select the latest version. [Import Statements docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-imports.html)
- Prefer `QtQuick.Controls.Basic` over `QtQuick.Controls` for controls customization. [customize a non-native style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76625756/the-current-style-does-not-support-customization-of-this-control)

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls.Basic

Page {
    id: root

    implicitWidth: 400
    implicitHeight: 290

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: ListModel {
            Component.onCompleted: {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                    append({
                        titleText: 'titleText,'.repeat(100),
                        ingredientsText: 'ingredientsText,'.repeat(100),
                        instructionsText: 'instructionsText,'.repeat(100)
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        delegate: Column {
            required property string titleText
            required property string ingredientsText
            required property string instructionsText

            spacing: 5
            padding: 5
            rightPadding: listView.ScrollBar.vertical.width
            width: listView.width - leftPadding - rightPadding

            Repeater {
                model: [titleText, ingredientsText, instructionsText]
                Label {
                    width: parent.width
                    text: modelData
                    color: ['#2af','#fac','#da5'][index];
                    wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                }
            }
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            id: scrollbar

            contentItem: Rectangle {
                radius: 2
                implicitWidth: 10
                implicitHeight: 100
                color: 'gray'
            }
        }
    }
}
```